# Object with Subdiv Surface won't be smoothed

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

This simple cylinder doesn't want to get smoothed out after a Subdiv Surface modifier.
It doesn't matter if I convert it to mesh, it won't get smoothed even after that!

[image]

The red lines are seams AND crease, except for the 3 longitudinal ones of course, that are only seams.

[image]

And here you can see the autosmooth active.

[image]

I think I tried any possible combination of Subdiv Surface settings, Smooth and Autosmooth settings, and as said also convert to mesh just to see exactly if the problem was in the modifier.
I also tried to merge vertexes, because sometimes this type of errors can arise from nearby or same position vertexes, but there's no exceeding vertex.
I'm stuck. Like a duck. And probably stupid as one too!

Comment: It would be better if you showed smooth shaded screenshot, not auto-smoothed, which would rule out one thing... Probably, your problem lies in the texture you use on the object. What if you view the object in solid mode, is it smooth? If the edges are baked into the texture, you won't get rid of them.

Comment: Check my answer, thank for your time.

Comment: Post your texture, it probably has edges baked into it... Also, use non-color for normal maps, not sRGB...

Comment: It has nothing baked, it's a flat texture with some noise on it, there is no straight line in it at all, I grant you. I work in CG for 30 years.

Comment: Can you upload .blend? Maybe it has custom split normal data, but I can keep guessing like that without seeing the blend. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486

Answer (score 0):

Turns out... it's the material.
I would have never imagined this but the normal map seems to annoy the smoothing of the mesh and I can't understand why.

Below you can see the same mesh with only changed material, simple material colored. The other 2 materials have just a tileable normal map applied.

[image]

Now the question is: why the Phong smoothing gets broken just because I apply a normal map?

[image]

Comment: color space shoult be **non-color**

Comment: That did actually something: it let me uncover that the shader has some problem with my normal maps, that are working perfectly in Unity though...